# What is the latency of IP over Infiniband compare with 10Gbps fibre network?

Tags: ip, latency

What is the latency of IP over Infiniband compare with 10Gbps fibre network?

10Gbps network is something like a Solarflare low latency NIC card. How well does IP over IB perform not just throughput but latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this page: http://www.mellanox.com/page/performance_infiniband (undated)

It compares 56G Infiniband to 40G and 10G Ethernet - apparently NICs/HBAs only, but you can get the basic idea.

Also, http://www.hpcadvisorycouncil.com/pdf/IB_and_10GigE_in_HPC.pdf (from 2009) states that 10GE has 5-6 times the latency of IB.

However, Ethernet latency can vary greatly with the specific switches used and (obviously) the number of hops required. Even the cable matters as 10GBASE-T has appr. 1.5 μs additional latency in comparison to 10GBASE-R due to additional encoding. Finally, the hardware generation has some significance as NIC latencies have progressively decreased over time.